# Google play error on tablet, your device not compatible with this version

Tags: android, google-play

On tablet, my application in the google play store shows an error, your device is not compatible with this version. After research, I found to include the elements in Manifest.

```
 <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" /> 
 <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Is it necessary to include these elements in the Manifest?

My Application is working is working fine when i manually install .apk, i have optimized the ui for different screen sizes, but problem is that when i try to download the application through google play store then google play store shows error, device is not compatible with this version.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary,i have an app on Play Store [Check this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.algorithmapps.restau).I haven't included these lines but still my app works in Tablets.But ofcourse i have made folders and values for every support screens like this image.Check the image below.

[image: ImageDrrr]